Open-source датасет
Всем привет!
Я хочу создать свою нейросеть, которая будет использоваться в коммерческих целях. В сети куча open-source датасетов, которые, как я понимаю, можно использовать для учёбы. Но меня волнут другое - можно ли использовать их в коммерческих целях ? Моя будущая нейросеть будет с платной лицензией. Не будет ли это использование таких датасетов нарушений авторских прав ?
Всех благ и заранее спасибо)

Почитай правила оупен-сорса, некоторые разрешают коммерция, но по определённым условиям и так далее, но это нужно читать.

Как было уже упомянуто выше - всё зависит от лицензии. Самая популярная Open Source лицензия - это MIT или Apache-2.0. Если видите их - проблем ожидать не стоит. Но я просто чувак из интернета, перед использованием внимательно прочитайте текст лицензии.
Обычно, в корне проекта есть стандартный файл LICENSE в котором указано, как минимум, название лицензии. Но обычно и текст тоже.
В GitHub, например, этот файл считывается и предоставляется в удобном виде.

Например, тут лицензия Apache-2.0. Она обязывает вас указывать авторство и запрещает, например, использовать логотип, торговою марку и т. д без разрешения.
Открываете, читаете.

Есть более интересные лицензии, типа GPL-3.0 и она связана уже с патентами на ПО, всякими Европейскими регуляторами и там уже нужно заморачиваться, вникать. Но самые распространенные лицензии как раз и являються самыми простыми.
Так же, стоит упомянуть, что для датасетов есть свои типы лицензий: CC-BY, ODbL.
В этом вопросе лучше один раз хорошо разобраться и больше никогда не страдать. Удачи с поисками.
Материалы:

Свободное программное обеспечение (рус)
Apache-2.0 license (en)
ODbL (en)
CC-BY (en)

